Auto generate binding types for Cloudflare Wokers
I have been working with Cloudflare workers for a while. One of the most annoying things is having to manually write the binding types for my worker since they are already in my wrangler.toml configuration file.
I was wondering if there was any way to have these auto generate from the wrangler.toml so that they would be immediately available on the env argument from the beginning.

You can use wrangler types to generate the type definitions from your wrangler.toml. You can view the documentation here.
If you want them to automatically make changes when you change the wrangler.toml, you can use the ts-plugin-workers TypeScript extension found here.
